# How to mock/test event listeners with mocha/jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, jestjs

```
class Router {
    constructor() {
        window.onhashchange = this.hashChange;
    }

    hashChange() {
        console.log('Hash Changed');
        return true;
    }
}

export default Router;
```

I am trying to find a way to test the above piece of code in node.js. But there is no `window` object in node. How to mock objects and test event listeners using mocha/jest? The goal is to test that `hashChange()` is invoked when URL hash is changed

Answer (score 2):

The [default test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) in `Jest` is a browser-like environment provided by `jsdom`.

`jsdom` provides `window` so it is available by default for tests running in `Jest`.

You can use `Jest` to test the above code like this:

```
class Router {
  constructor() {
      window.onhashchange = this.hashChange;
  }

  hashChange() {
      console.log('Hash Changed');
      return true;
  }
}

test('Router', () => {
  const hashChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(Router.prototype, 'hashChange');
  const router = new Router();
  window.onhashchange();
  expect(hashChangeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

Comment: `The default test environment in Jest is a browser-like environment provided by jsdom`

So, do i need to add jsdom to my package.json? or does it come with jest?

Comment: @lch it’s included with jest and is used automatically with the default configuration settings